# Вывести несколько таблиц из DataSet на DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть WPF приложение, в классе `DAL` которого реализуется чтение данных из БД и запись полученной таблицы в `DataSet`, в класс `Storage`. Таблицы точно попадают в `Storage.DataSet`. И есть класс - вью модель `MainVM` который отвечает за отображение данных в `DataGrid`. Собственно вопрос - как заполнить этот `DataGrid` таблицами из `Storage.DataSet` наиболее правильно c точки зрения MVVM ? Сейчас я пробую решить это так  :

Вот коллекция которая стоит как `ItemsSource` для грида :

```
 FundCollection = new ObservableCollection<Fund>();
```

где класс `Fund` :

```
 public class Fund
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string CountPaper { get; set; }
    }
```

Теперь, в конструктор класса я пишу цикл, для добавления всех строк из `DataSet`

```
  public class MainVM
   {
    public MainVM()
    {
     for (int i = 0; i < set.Tables["Fund"].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                FundCollection.Add(new Fund()
                {
                    Type = set.Tables["Fund"].Rows[i][2].ToString(),
                    Date = set.Tables["Fund"].Rows[i][1].ToString(),
                    CountPaper = set.Tables["Fund"].Rows[i][3].ToString()
                });
            }
           }
          }
```

И тут есть 2 проблемы : во первых - в грид попадает только  1 строка даже  если их 100+. и во вторых - насколько я знаю записывать циклы в конструкторы класса очень плохая практика. Посоветуйте, как исправить этот ГКод ?